# How can I insert a value to a table thats inside a table

Tags: lua, associative-array, lua-table

I am just testing out my knowledge and I want to know how I can insert a string value like a name into a nested table.

I have tried `table.insert()` but I cant seem to insert into the nested table

```lua
whitelist = {
    owners = {"Owner","AnotherOwner","John"},
    users = {"Jack","Jill","username"}
}

table.insert(whitelist,2,"Q") --What I want to do
--[[for index,table in pairs(whitelist) do 
    print(index)
    for key,value in pairs(table) do
        print('\t',value)
    end
end
(I want to use this later after inserting to see if it works)
]]--
```

I expected it to print out both tables with an added value of `"Q"`into `users` but I get an error:

> Position out of bounds

Answer (score 3):

You want to insert in the `users` list, so use `table.insert(whitelist.users,"Q")`.